# Access violation in UIB EventCallback

Tags: delphi, firebird, access-violation, firebird2.5, uib

With EurekaLog, I found this Access Violation in my application:

```
 2.2 Address       : 00404A77
 2.5 Type          : EAccessViolation
 2.6 Message       : Access violation at address 00404A77 in module 'MyApp.exe'. Write of address 4F4F4E30.
```

Callstack:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Address |Module        |Unit           |Class          |Procedure/Method         |Line    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*Exception Thread: ID=3748; Priority=??; Class=                                           |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|00404A77|MyApp.exe     |               |               |                         |        |
|75E1CD33|kernel32.dll  |               |               |LocalAlloc               |        |
|70BB2C72|MSVCR80.dll   |               |               |__set_flsgetvalue        |        |
|76F16FF2|ntdll.dll     |               |               |KiUserExceptionDispatcher|        |
|0064FC04|MyApp.exe     |uib.pas        |               |EventCallback            |4430[5] |
|70BB29A0|MSVCR80.dll   |               |               |_endthreadex             |        |
|75E1ED6A|kernel32.dll  |               |               |GetDriveTypeW            |        |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

And the code from [uib.pas](https://sourceforge.net/p/uib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/uib.pas#l4424):

```
procedure EventCallback(UserData: Pointer; Length: Smallint; Updated: PAnsiChar); cdecl;
begin
  if (Length > 0) and (Updated <> nil) then
  if (Assigned(UserData) and Assigned(Updated)) then
  with TUIBEventThread(UserData) do
  begin
    Move(Updated^, FResultBuffer^, Length);
    FQueueEvent := True;
    FSignal.SetEvent;
  end;
end;
```

Any idea what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you decipher the EurekaLog report? Which line of code is the error on?

Comment: With statements give me the heebie-jeebies. (I think I've been overly conditioned.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: According to call stack, error is on the Move(..) line.

Comment: Clearly the destination pointer is duff.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments, the line which is raising the access violation is the call to `Move`. So the diagnostics are telling you that the pointer to the destination buffer does not point to a valid buffer of whose length is at least `Length`.

In other words, your problem is that either:

- `FResultBuffer` is an invalid pointer, or
- The buffer that `FResultBuffer` refers to is not sufficiently long.